# what should be the default value of file in react-typescript in useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, multer

How do I initialize a file through useState in React Typescript?

```
 const [images, setImages] = useState<File>();

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        image: File
    });
```

I am getting file as undefined when I am trying to upload an image.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, for instance, you could use

```
onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                      if (!event.target.files) return
                      setImages(event.target.files[0])
                    }}
```

inside input tug.